# Проблема в react-native-text-input-mask

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Установил себе react-native-text-input-mask и сразу же вышел такая ошибка ((( Помогите!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приложите в вопрос код модуля, в котором Вы используете компоненты `react-native-text-input-mask`

Comment: Установил нормальную другую библиотеку react-native-masked-text))

Comment: примите мои поздравления) тогда закройте этот вопрос, чтобы явно уведомить систему о решенном вопросе. с Уважением